# What is the difference between "tribute" and "homage"?

Tags: differences

What is the difference between "tribute" and "homage"? Pay tribute and pay homage.
Here are the definitions I found in LDOCE:
tribute: 
1- something you say, do, or give in order to express your respect or admiration for s/one 
homage: something you do to show respect for s/one or sth.

Comment: Hello, 325. What differences do you find in dictionary definitions?

Comment: Hello, you can call my username with an "@". No need to write all of it. I looked them up in the LDOCE:
tribute: 1- something you say, do, or give in order to express your respect or admiration for s/one
homage: something you do to show respect for s/one or sth.

Comment: Have you ever thought about making an actual username? btw, research should go in the question description, and not the question comments

Comment: @Bobby''V0ight''Peru--------: No, I don't see any reason to do that.
And about your quote that "research should go in the question description", I presuppose that the ones that are going to answer me, are that much expert that don't need the definitions which are just written in dictionaries.

Comment: I would argue that there is a reason, to differentiate you between the hundreds of other users on this site that go by user#####. As to the latter part of your comment, the purpose of research in the question description is to show that you yourself have given the question some thought, and it's common courtesy. It's also to make it easier on the answerers when they already have the basic information in the question itself, so they don't have to look it up themselves.

Comment: As you can see from the three close votes you've already garnered, this question is dangerously close to be put on hold for lack of research effort.

Comment: @Bobby''V0ight''Peru--------: Why do you want to differentiate me? There is not a chance to mistake me for somebody else because I don't answer  too many questions and The questions that I ask, don't have many users that want to answer me.

Comment: I agree that it would be innocuous to add this information to the post, yet I think that if s/one still doesn't know what these words' meaning are, cannot help me with the difference between them.

Comment: @Bobby''V0ight''Peru--------: Mutual respect is the matter here and keep it in mind that I don't care even if you not only put this question on hold, but also delete me from this site.

Comment: You must not have read the site's rules then, because they clearly outline that one should extensively research a question before posting it. You clearly haven't done that and instead decided to post a one-line description. So how exactly are YOU showing respect to the answers that you want access to?

Comment: I'd done research before posting; otherwise, I never asked it here. I never ask anything before researching. Keep this in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Historically, they were utterly different. *Tribute* was material wealth paid to a conqueror or ruler by the conquered or subjects. *Homage* was the act of showing deference to a ruler or conqueror.

In modern use, as others have said, there is not much difference between them. But my reaction to other answers' bald statement "They are synonyms" was "No they are certainly not!"

Comment: So, about the modern usage, is there any difference between saying "I pay tribute to someone" and "I pay homage to someone" in the terms of respect, putting aside the fact that homage is formal?

Comment: I think there is, @user3257464. To me, _pay tribute_ means acknowledging somebody for something they have done; _pay homage_ means referring to something they've done that has had an influence on the work of the person paying homage. Sometimes by the work itself referring to their work, sometimes by the person making direct acknowledgment of their influence.

Comment: 'In modern use, as others have said, there is not much difference between them. But my reaction to other answers' bald statement "They are synonyms" was "No they are certainly not!" ' doesn't make sense. Synonyms are most sensibly defined as 'pairs etc of words or larger expressions that have the same or very nearly the same meaning in at last some of their usages'. An 'always interchangeable' requirement would make the term 'synonym' virtually worthless.

Comment: Sense or not, @EdwinAshworth, that was genuinely my reaction. It didn't occur to me until I read the other answers that there might be a context in which they could appear interchangeable. It may be relevant that last week I was studying Act I Scene 2 of The Tempest: "To give him annual tribute, do him homage, / Subject his coronet to his crown, and bend / The dukedom yet unbowed - alas, poor Milan - / To such ignoble stooping"

Answer (score 0):

They are synonyms and are often used interchangeably.

***[Pay tribute/homage](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pay%20tribute/homage%20to):***

> - to honor and praise (someone) *We gather here today to pay tribute/homage to a great woman.*

Merriam-Webster

***[Pay tribute/homage to someone](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/pay-tribute-homage-to-someone)***:

> - to say or do something that shows you respect and admire someone a lot
>
>   - *We are here tonight to pay tribute to one of the greatest actors of all time.*

Macmillan Dictionary